# Spam Filter in the Stack Exchange Website

Tags: feature-request, spam

Recently, in the tex.stackechange.com site, there was a question which was detected as a spam.  I dont know if the question is deleted now. When I saw it, It had got 5 downvotes. I request the developers to develop or enhance the security of the website by,

1. Adding a Spam Filter
2. Enabling Encryption

[image]

Comment: rather than downvote, it's more effective to flag a spam post for moderator attention.  it only requires reputation of 15, and the moderators are very quick taking care of such problems.

Comment: Related: [Recent Mass Football Spam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192820/168244) (from a couple of months back)

Comment: Indeed, as @barbarabeeton says flagging is the best plan: there is some 'back end' stuff which 'learns' from such flags.

Comment: I do not understand where and how encryption should be used. Or do you think of a CAPTCHA mechanism?

Comment: @Speravir: There is already a CAPTCHA mechanism on TeX.SE

Comment: See for example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28661/anti-spam-filter

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I know, but not for _every_ question and answer …

Comment: @Speravir: That's true, which is good on one hand, on other hand however...